# UIWebView cuts off bottom of content

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, highcharts

I am working on an app in which I have several webViews and in them I render various charts using javascript library HighCharts.
Here is part of my view controller's view in which such a web view is placed

[image]

"Country Name" and everything above is part of web view, while "Legend" is in a UILabel.
As you can see, 'y' in "Country Name" is cut off at the bottom. I made the label at bottom transparent and even set `webView.scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO` as well as change that scroll view's `contentInsets`, but that doesn't really change anything (and I realize that turning clipsToBounds off might be wrong, I was just checking if the problem has anything to do with it).
(EDIT: Replaced fragments with full html)

This is the html template that I use. In the final html all "%%" are replaced with just "%" and "%@" are replaced with chart data.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
              $('#chart_container').highcharts({
                                               chart: {
                                               type: '%@',
                                               spacing: [10, 0, 0, 0],
                                               zoomType: 'x'
                                               },
                                               title: {
                                               text: null
                                               },
                                               xAxis: {
                                               categories: %@,
                                               title: {
                                               text: '%@',
                                               style: {
                                               fontSize: '13.0px'
                                               }
                                               },
                                               minRange: 1,
                                               labels: {
                                               rotation: -45,
                                               style: {
                                               fontSize: '13.0px'
                                               }
                                               }
                                               },
                                               yAxis: {
                                               title: {
                                               text: '%@',
                                               style: {
                                               fontSize: '12.0px'
                                               }
                                               },
                                               labels: {
                                               style: {
                                               fontSize: '14.0px'
                                               }
                                               }
                                               },
                                               tooltip: {
                                               shared: true,
                                               headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 18.0px">{point.key}</span><br/>',
                                               %@
                                               style: {
                                               fontSize: '16.0px'
                                               }
                                               },
                                               legend: {
                                               enabled: false
                                               },
                                               %@
                                               series: %@,
                                               credits: {
                                               enabled: false
                                               },
                                               exporting: {
                                               enabled: false
                                               }
                                               });
              });

              function toggleSeries(index) {
                  var chart = $('#chart_container').highcharts();
                  chart.tooltip.hide();
                  %@
              }
        </script>
        </head>

<body style="height: 100%%; min-height: 100%%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow: visible">
    <script src="highcharts.js">
        </script>
    <script src="exporting.js">
        </script>
    <div id="chart_container" style="height: 100%%; overflow: visible"></div>
</body>
```

Any idea where does this problem come from and how can it be fixed?

Comment: could you show full Highcharts code? Have you tried to set `chart.marginBottom` to higher value than default one?

Comment: @PawełFus I added full html to the question. I tried setting margin on the chart div.

Comment: Why you have: `height: 100%%` - is that correct? Just asking. Also, why you have disabled spacing: `spacing: [10, 0, 0, 0]` ? Add some spacing at the bottom, will be working.

Comment: I resetted back to default spacing and it's working great. :) You can post it as an answer here so I could mark it as accepted. :) And about the 100%% part, this template is used as a format string so I had to add an extra "%" as otherwise it would be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in setting for a chart:

```
spacing: [10, 0, 0, 0]
```

After removing this, auto-calculation for spacing prevents from this problem.